# What is the correct typedef for an opaque C pointer to a C++ class?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

There are dozens upon dozens of SO questions and blog posts that describe wrapping a C++ class with a C API. Example [Wrapping C++ class API for C consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1588788/wrapping-c-class-api-for-c-consumption)

Most of these answers and blogposts go for something like this:

```
typedef void* CMyClass;
```

But others say that this is bad because it provides no type safety. They propose various variations of opaque structs, without any explanation. I could just copy the above snippet and move on with my life (which I will do in the meantime), but I'd like to know once and for all

- Which form is the best?
- Which guarantees does it provide over `void*`?
- How does it work?

Comment: The problem is that other pointers can convert to `void *` without a compiler warning but if you declared `typedef struct CMyClass_ *CMyClass;` you need an explicit cast.  Example: https://godbolt.org/g/e5QqrX

Comment: Relevant: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#cpp-objs-passed-to-c

Comment: Don't typedef pointers! Said that, which other way do those critics recommend? Why does it not work for you?

Comment: C is supported from C++, but the reverse is not true.  This means no valid general mechanism is available to manage classes from C.  Assume for example a global instance (`static`) used in a C program... who's calling the constructor for that object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `struct MyType` in C++.

Use `typedef struct MyType* pMyType;` as your common handle.

Your "C" APIs should compile in both C and C++ (with `extern "C"` wrappers in C++ to get correct linkage).  And you'll get close to max type safety.

Now, `struct MyHandle{void* private_ptr;};` is another option: this avoids exposing the name of the C++ type to C.  And so long as you isolate direct interaction with `private_ptr` to a handful of functions, it will be as type safe everywhere else.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the C++ declaration. `struct T` and `class T` are different declarations, and Clang for example will emit an error if a mix of `struct` and `class` is used to refer to the same name.

Comment: @MatthieuM. how do you trigger this error (assuming `-pedantic-errors -Wno-error -Wall -Wextra`)? At most I can get a `-Wmismatched-tags` with clang 6.0, but it's obviously a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Ruslan: Good question. I only ever compile with `-Werror` so it might be a warning. Pretty useful for portability, as well, since in MSVC's ABI [`struct` and `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712514/can-gcc-produce-struct-class-name-mismatches-like-vs) have different linkage.

Comment: I ended up going with the struct with private pointer, as it turns out my C++ API returns shared_ptr, and that's the only sane way I could find. It also requires no casting at all, which is nice.

Comment: For C programmers, hiding a pointer behind a `typedef` is widely considered bad style. In this special case, it might be justified because the pointer points to something unknown in C, so you could argue to provide just an "opaque handle". Still, strictly speaking, a "C++ struct" can be different from a struct in C (think e.g. vtables), so I'd always pick the second option.

Comment: @felix I am unaware of a C or C++ compiler that doesn't have `struct foo*` compatibility between C and C++.  The actual struct can differ.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with `void *` is that it gives you no protection from accidentally assigning an incompatible pointer.

```
typedef void *CMyClass;
int i = 1;
CMyClass c = &i; // No complaints
```

If you instead typedef to some unique opaque type the compiler will help you.

```
typedef struct MyClass *CMyClass;
int i = 1;
CMyClass c = &i; // BOOM!
```

I think in C this is not an error but Clang 6.0 warns me with  (even without any warnings enabled)

```
warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'CMyClass' (aka 'struct MyClass *') with an expression of type 'int *'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that `void *` is indeed not a good choice because it makes API more error prone by silently accepting any unrelated pointers. So the better idea would be to add a forward declaration to some struct and accept a pointer to that struct:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

struct CMyClassTag;
typedef struct CMyClassTag CMyClass;

void CMyClass_Work(CMyClass * p_self);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The next step is to explicitly tell user that this pointer is opaque and is not supposed to be dereferenced by hiding pointer as unnecessary implementation detail:

```
typedef struct CMyClassTag * CMyClassHandle;

void CMyClass_Work(CMyClassHandle h_my_class);
```

Additionally rather that relying on user to correctly utilize this interface you can make real handle type rather than an opaque pointer. This could be done in several ways, but the main idea is to pass some obscure integer identifier and perform mapping from it to real pointer on library side at runtime:

```
typedef uintptr_t CMyClassHandle;

void CMyClass_Work(CMyClassHandle h_my_class);

// impl
void CMyClass_Work(CMyClassHandle h_my_class)
{
     auto it{s_instances_map.find(h_my_class)};
     if(s_instances_map.end() != it)
     {
         auto & self{it->second};
         // ...
     }
}
```