# Must this code works?

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I have the next sample code that compiles with gcc (4.7.2 using -std=c++11):

```
template<class C>
struct template_test
{
    C testing() const
    {
        return C();
    }
};

class A;

struct test : public template_test<A> // (1)
{};

struct A
{};

int main()
{
    test t;
}
```

At point (1) the function `template_test<A>::testing()` is instantiated, and use a function of `A`, specifically its default constructor. Therefore, `test` contains this instantiated function as a function member. However, at this point `A` is an incomplete type, and C++ prohibits you to use members of a incomplete type.

Is this a `positive` gcc's error or is there another explanation?

Comment: Not related to the central point of your question but clang gives me a warning because of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866425/mixing-class-and-struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is template_test::testing() not instantiated at (1), it's *never* instantiated in this program. Template members are only instantiated on use, and testing() isn't used. To make this more clear, change the code slightly to:

```
template<class C>
struct template_test
{
    C testing() const
    {
        return C::foo();
    }
};

class A;

struct test : public template_test<A> // (1)
{};

struct A
{};

int main()
{
    test t;
}
```

which also compiles and runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

That's all right. The `testing()` member function won't get instantiated until you will actually invoke it. To see this, try rewriting it as follows:

```
C testing() const
{
    static_assert(C::value, "Error!");
    return C();
}
```

You'll see that no compilation error is issued until you try to invoke the function, but the static assert will be triggered when you add `t.testing()` to your `main()` function.

In other words, your premise that *"At point (1) the function `template_test<A>::testing()` is instantiated"* is incorrect.

Comment: How much code is instantiated when I instance a class, but I don't use any member?

Comment: If I substitute `C::value` by `false`, I get a compile error always (even commenting the declaration `test t;`). If `testing` is not instantiated, why does compilation fail?

Comment: @Peregring-lk: If you don't use any member, no *code* will be instantiated. Also, if you replace `C::value` by `false`, the compiler will detect that your template has no possible valid instantiation (the condition `false` does not depend on any template parameter), so it can directly emit a compilation error before even instantiating the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a template with an incomplete type, this is OK.

The member function `testing` returns *an instance* of an incomplete type, which is *not OK* (but whether or not that's OK only comes into discussion when it's instantiated). However, you never call that function, so it is never instantiated, and thus there is no error. Instantiating the structure alone (and calling its constructor/destructor) is harmless.

Therefore, GCC is correct in letting you compile that. It would fail the moment you try to call `testing`.

Comment: It wouldn't fail actually, because at the point of instantiation (when you call `testing()` in `main()`) the definition of `A` is visible.