# Visual C++ 2015 linker error when forward declaring a struct as class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following code (more than one file involved)...

```
//--- SomeInterface.h
struct SomeInterface
{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
  virtual ~SomeInterface(){}
};

//--- SomeInterfaceUser.h
#include <memory> //shared_ptr

class SomeInterface;
//NOTE: struct SomeInterface... causes linker error to go away...

class SomeInterfaceUser
{
  public:
    explicit SomeInterfaceUser(std::shared_ptr<SomeInterface> s);
};

//SomeInterfaceUser.cpp
#include "SomeInterfaceUser.h"
#include "SomeInterface.h"
SomeInterfaceUser::SomeInterfaceUser(std::shared_ptr<SomeInterface> s)
{
}

//SomerInterfaceUserInstantiator.cpp
#include "SomeInterfaceUser.h"
#include "SomeInterfaceImpl.h"

struct SomeInterfaceImpl : SomeInterface
{
  virtual void foo(){}
};

void test()
{
  SomeInterfaceUser x{std::make_shared<SomeInterfaceImpl>()};
}
```

Using the Visual C++ compiler, I get a linker error (LNK2019). Using GCC 4.8.4 this is not the case. Changing the forward declaration **class SomeInterface** to **struct SomeInterface** makes the linker error go away. I always thought that one should be able to use class/struct interchangeably? The interface of SomeInterfaceUser should not depend on whether SomeInterface is defined as class or struct, not so?

Is this a Visual C++ bug. I cannot find anything relating to it. I suspect the fact that the struct is used as template parameter has something to do with it.

Your help appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work fine here. Please post all your compiler and linker settings and make sure that you've correctly posted all file contents.

Comment: @ChristianHackl. I have quite a complex project, but changing a forward declaration from struct to class should not make a linker error go away. Have you moved the various classes to their respective files?

Comment: Well, does the error only happen in your complex project or does it also happen with the example code you have posted?

Comment: @Christian Hackl. The example is a simplification. I'll have to see, to be honest.

Comment: OK. I don't know, personally. I know that VC has a compiler warning for `struct`/`class` mismatches, but I am not personally aware of linker errors. Then again, I've never had unmodifiable code with this problem.

Comment: I might be way off with C++ standard, but `struct` and `class` are the same except that for `struct` the access specifier defaults to `public` while for `class` to `private`. For example in VC2k12 a minimal example that I created works (but it throws a warning _C4624_ - related to destructor). Try using `class` and make the members `public` (or `protected` where appropriate).

Comment: @nm, Just following the part that you cite. I've always class/struct interchangeable (at least 10 years now). Here is another answer referring to the same thing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866425/mixing-class-and-struct

Comment: @nm, I've found the following excerpt from Herb Sutters xc++ errata (http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++-errata.htm):

"It's perfectly legal and standards-conforming to forward-declare a class as a struct and vice versa. In most of the book I've tended to avoid doing that, though. Why?.... Sigh."

Still not sure about the verdict.

Comment: I've seen this before and always fixed the problem by forward declaring and declaring them using the same keyword.  I think it has something to do with the way MSVC mangles names.

Answer (score 9):

I've just been facing the same problem with both VC++ 2010 and VC++ 2017, and after some tests I've found that the problem resides in the symbol name the compiler gives to structs and classes internally.

Here a minimum example consisting in three files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"
struct Foo {};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  bar(&foo);
  return 0;
}
```

**bar.h**

```
class Foo;
void bar(Foo* f);
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"

void bar(Foo* foo) {}
```

When the project is compiled the following errors and warnings appear:

> warning C4099: 'Foo': type name first seen using 'class' now seen using 'struct'
>
> see declaration of 'Foo'
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl bar(struct Foo *)" (?bar@@YAXPAUFoo@@@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Now, I swapped the `struct` and `class` declarations, so `main.cpp` and `bar.h` are now:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"
class Foo {};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  bar(&foo);
  return 0;
}
```

**bar.h**

```
struct Foo;
void bar(Foo* f);
```

As expected, the error still pops up:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl bar(class Foo *)" (?bar@@YAXPAVFoo@@@Z) referenced in function _main

**BUT**, and this is the interesting part, see that the symbols for the expected function (the one used in `main()`) in each case differ:

- **?bar@@YAXPAUFoo@@@Z** (when the parameter is a `struct`)
- **?bar@@YAXPAVFoo@@@Z** (when the parameter is a `class`)

---

**Conclusion**

*The compiler gives slightly different names if the type is a struct or a class.*

The linker then cannot find the proper definition because it is looking for a different one: `bar.cpp` defines one with the forward declaration, but for the moment it is called in `main.cpp` the actual declaration has taken placed, so a different function name is given in the symbols table.

#### Update (2023-02-03)

I've just seen that clang is able to report this issue:

> error: 'Foo' defined as a struct here but previously declared as a class; this is valid, but may result in linker errors under the Microsoft C++ ABI [-Werror,-Wmismatched-tags]

Comment: Just bumped on the same issue, and took me a 2~3 hours to figure out the reason. Never thought that MSVC(VS 2017) makes the distinction up to a point of issuing a linker error because of this.