# declare a defined class as a struct inside a template parameter

Tags: c++

A **class** `A` is defined and implemented. Later it's declared as a **struct** as the template argument of `std::unique_ptr`. The compiler(g++10.1) complains nothing about it and the program can be run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    std::string info = "Hello World!";
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<struct A> a{new A};
    std::cout << a->info << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If I define a without the `new A`

```
std::unique_ptr<struct A> a;
```

The code can still be compiled but there is a segmentation fault during runtime. So why is this possible?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<struct A> a;` without the `new` creates a `unique_ptr` that points to `nullptr`, so why do you expect that this should not result into runtime problems at `a->info`?

Comment: See also [What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c) Brief answer: almost none.

Comment: Note that `A` is automatically `typedef`ined so you don't have to use `struct` or `class` to declare variables of `A`. Just: `std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<A>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's allowed to mix `class` and `struct` in a *declaration*, it's only an issue in a *definition* of a class. Refer to [Mixing class and struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866425/mixing-class-and-struct) for more details.

The seg fault in the second case comes from *null pointer* access, a form of undefined behavior.

`std::unique_ptr<struct A> a;` initializes `a` to an "empty" state. Then `a->info` will access a null pointer, which in your case causes a seg fault.

Comment: Dereferencing a null pointer causes undefined behaviour.   One possible outcome of undefined behaviour is a seg fault.   There are many other possible outcomes though - it is, for example, quite possible that the OPs code - when built with a different compiler, or even run on a machine with more memory - will run without any symptoms.